# Classic ASP and JSON: What parser/serializer should I use?

Tags: json, asp-classic

I have to handle JSON data on Classic ASP. I *could* use server-side JScript, but as there *are* ASP implementations, I think I should stick to just one server-side language.

I found two different projects which are conveniently distinguishable from each other:

- [aspjon](https://code.google.com/p/aspjson/)
- [ASPJSON](http://www.aspjson.com/)

I can’t make out the advantages or drawbacks. Actually, I’d prefer my JavaScript helpers, i.e. the `JSON` object and its methods plus simple access to object properties.

Comment: Your question isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow as recommendations for Software or Tools are not ideal questions for this format. Having said that, they are both equally good. Personally though I find [aspjson](https://code.google.com/p/aspjson/) slightly easier to use and work with.

Comment: Not sure why you refuse to work with serverside javascript. I've used the ASP Xtreme Evolution JSON parser (based on Douglas Crockford json2.js) on small scale without issues. Source :   https://github.com/nagaozen/asp-xtreme-evolution/blob/master/lib/axe/classes/Parsers/json2.asp

Comment: I thought it was barely eligible as a question, since you could rephrase it asking “Do both pojects help me with my programming problem?” (handling JSON data) or redraft it like “Are these software tools commonly (and in production) used by programmers?”—thank you anyway, I’ll look into your comments. Still I’d find a comparison helpful for other people with this issue.

Comment: @dakab Problem is always going to be with a question like this is it's going to be opinion based and therefore no right or wrong answer. Either of those libraries will do the job, dig into each one yourself and weight up the pros and cons. Do they have a good community around them?, Are they still being maintained?, What syntax do I prefer and find easier to work with?

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother with anything else but asp-xtreme-evolution JSON2 implementation. You can use server side object modeling which is great to keep your code clean using something like ASP.

https://github.com/nagaozen/asp-xtreme-evolution/blob/master/lib/axe/classes/Parsers/json2.asp